# jquery validate plugin mimetype

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my form when submitting. A message appears asking me to enter a valid mimetype value. I can not find the exact value of the matlab mimetype. Please can you help me.
     Here is the source code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html   dir="ltr"
        lang="fr-FR"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta   http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
        content="IE=10"/>
    <meta   http-equiv="Content-type"
        content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta   http-equiv="Expires"
        content="0"/>
    <title th:text="${@environment.getProperty('spring.application.title') + ' - ' + serviceTitle} + ' - Livrer le DDX'"></title>
    <link id="favicon"
        type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
        rel="shortcut icon"
        href="images/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta   name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link   rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link   id="mainCSS"    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"    href="css/mainBS.css"/>
    <link   id="workflowStageCSS"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"    href="css/workflow-stage.css"/>
    <link   id="uploadDDXCSS"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"    href="css/uploadDDX.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>                  <div class="articleBody">
                            <form  id="ddxForm" name="ddxForm"  method="POST"   enctype="multipart/form-data"   th:action="${@environment.getProperty('server.context-path') + 'uploadDDX'}" >
                                <p class="ddx-block"> 
                                    <label  id="ddx-file-label"
                                    for="ddx-file"  class="ddx-file-label"
                                    >Fichier matlab(*):</label> <input id="ddx-file"
                                    type="file"
                                    name="ddx-file" 
                                    class="ddx-file"
                                    accept=".m"
                                    th:required="true"/>                                   
                                </p><div><hr />                         
                                     <input id="ddx-next" name="ddx-next"
                                        type="submit" value="Continuer &gt;&gt;"/> <hr /></div>
                                </form></div>       
                            </article>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
        <script>
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
      success:"valid"
    });
            $("#ddxForm").validate({
                rules:{
                    "ddx-file":{
                        required:true,
                        extension:"m"
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't see any messages set for the jQuery validate plugin...so if a message saying `to enter a valid mimetype value` really appears then it's not from the jQuery validate plugin.

Comment: Please, how to solve the mimetype problem?